# Implications of Mule runtime version change from 3.8.x and 3.9 to 3.9.2

Tags: mule, mule-esb

Have a few projects that need to run at the same time so have one run/debug configuration. Not all projects have the same mule runtime (EE) and I want all of them under the same runtime version. One is 3.8.4, another – 3.9.0 and the rest – 3.9.2. What are the main implications that I should be aware of?